# Proving that the sequence $n^{(-1)^{n}}$ is divergent

Tags: real-analysis

I would like to prove that the sequence $n^{(-1)^{n}}$ is divergent.

My thoughts: I know $(-1)^n$ is divergent, so $n$ to the power of a divergent sequence is still divergent? I am not sure how to give a proper proof, pls help!

Comment: Hint: the sequence contain a divergent subsequence (for $n$ even).

Comment: n to the power of a divergent sequence isn't true if |n| < 1.  Which in this case it isn't.  Instead note that for any odd n > M > 1  1/M then a_n = 1/n < 1/M whereas for any even n > M then a_n > M > 1/M.  so for  $\epsilon = M - 1/M   > 0$ and any $M > 1$ we can find $n, m > M$ so that $|n^{(-1)^n} - m^{(-1)^m}| > \epsilon$.

Comment: Another hint: If it's convergent, it's bounded.

Comment: @EmilioNovati and also for odd $n$

Comment: @Hugh For odd $n$, $n^{(-1)^n}=n^{-1}$, which converges to $0$ as $n\to\infty$.

Comment: @fleabood But $|n|<1$ doesn't make sense because $n$ isn't a constant.  A better counterexample would be one where $a_n$ is divergent but stays sufficiently below $0$ so that $n^{a_n} \to 0$.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut My bad, I was considering the sum of $n^{-1}$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint**. By setting $$u_n:=n^{(-1)^n}$$ one gets that
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty}u_{2n}=\infty \neq 0 =\lim_{n \to \infty}u_{2n+1}
$$ thus the sequence $\left\{ u_n \right\}$ is *divergent*.

Answer (score 4):

The argument that "n to the power of a divergent sequence is divergent" does not make sense (consider $n^{-n}$ for example.). Regarding your sequence: if this sequence were convergent against some limit value $a$, then every subsequence would have to converge against the same value $a$. Now look at the subsequences for $n$ even and odd, respectively.

Answer (score 0):

note that $$(-1)^{n}=-1$$ if $n$ is odd and $$(-1)^{n}=1$$ if $n$ is even.

Answer (score 0):

Set $u_n=n^{(-1)^n}$? Explicitly, $u_{2n}=2n$,  $u_{2n+1}=\dfrac1{2n+1}$.

If the sequence were convergent, all subsequences would converge to the same limit.  However  we see the subsequence of odd terms converges to $0$, whereas the subsequence of even terms tends to $+\infty$.

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of correct answers. Here's a suggestion for how to attack a problem like this.

Before you try to invoke abstract principles like

> $n$ to the power of a divergent sequence is still divergent

which you rightly wonder about (hence your "?") try *writing out the first few terms*:

$$
1, 2, \frac{1}{3}, 4, \frac{1}{5}, 6, \ldots
$$

Then you can easily see that the sequence doesn't converge and can set about proving it.

Answer (score 0):

Or to be direct...

Let $r \in \mathbb R$.  Let $\epsilon > 0$

For any $M$ let $m > \max (r +  \epsilon, M); m$  even. So $m - r > \epsilon > 0$.

Then $|m^{(-1)^m} - r| = |m -r|= m-r > \epsilon$.  So the sequence doesn't converge to any real $r$.

Answer (score -1):

If $n$ even then $-1^n = 1 $
$$n^1 = n\Rightarrow \lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty}{({n})} = \infty$$

If $n$ odd then $-1^n = -1 $
$$n^{-1} = \frac{1}{n}\Rightarrow \lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty}{(\frac{1}{n})} = 0$$

Comment: $n^{(-1)^n} \neq n^{-1n}$, generally

Comment: The sentence [$x_n$ converges to $0$ only when $n$ is odd, otherwise diverges to $n$] is absurd on several counts. Can you tell at least two?

Comment: @Did the subsequence $x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_9, x_{11}, x_{13}, \ldots$ also converges to zero. What is the other reason?

Comment: @Santiago "Diverges to $n$" is unsound, "$(x_n)$ diverges to $+\infty$" is ok but "$x_n$ diverges to $y_n$" is not.